# How can I count the number of times a pattern appears

Tags: perl, count

I am trying to count the number of occurrences that a particular string appears in a text document so that the string can be deleted if it occurs less than 5 times. The text file has a list of dates that are formatted as `2015-06-16 07:40:00`.

After processing the incoming data from `2015-06-16 07:40:00` to `2015061607`, I want to count the number of times that this string appears. I have the processing of the incoming data correct but I don't know how to count the occurrences of the string.

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

foreach $file (@ARGV) {

open (OUT, ">/d2/aschwa/scripts_and_programs/NST_Scripts/data_organizers/Filtered_$file") || die "Cannot open specified file\n";

open (RAW, "/d2/aschwa/scripts_and_programs/NST_Scripts/data_organizers/$file") || die "Cannot open specified file to be processed\n";

while(<RAW>) {

    $event = $_;
    chop($event);
    @event = split (',', $event);
    ($date_time, $var1, $var2, $var3) = @event[(0,1,2,3)];

    @date_time = split (' ', $date_time);
    ($date, $time) = @date_time[(0,1)];

    @date_mod = split ('-', $date);
    ($year, $month, $day) = @date_mod[(0,1,2)];
    @time = split (':', $time);
    ($hr, $mins, $sec) = @time[(0,1,2)];

    $datehr = $year . $month . $day . $hr;

    foreach ($event) {
        $count{$datehr}++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you counting it at each line or in the whole file?

Comment: I'm counting the occurrences in the whole file

Comment: my answer was wrong, please unaccept it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a regular expression rather than repeated calls to `split`

This example reads through each file twice, counting the dates on the first pass and printing those lines whose dates appear more than five times on the second

It doesn't compress the date-time as you have done, but captures just up to the hour field, so the keys of the `%count` hash look like `2015-06-16 07`. It is only extra code to remove the punctuation and isn't necessary to make the program work

I've also used `autodie`, which has been available since v5.10 of Perl and automatically checks the status of `open` and `chdir` calls for you. It is also best practice to use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use constant DIR => '/d2/aschwa/scripts_and_programs/NST_Scripts/data_organizers';

chdir DIR;

for my $file ( @ARGV ) {

    open my $raw_fh, '<', $file;

    my %count;

    while ( <$raw_fh> ) {
        ++$count{$1} if /^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d):\d\d:\d\d/;
    }

    seek $raw_fh, 0, 0; # Rewind input file

    open my $out_fh, '>', "Filtered_$file";

    while ( <$raw_fh> ) {
        print unless /^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d):\d\d:\d\d/ and $count{$1} < 5;
    }

}
```